# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '')' at line 1

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am coding in VB.NET and I'm getting this error when I'm trying to insert a record into my SQL database.

```
Public Sub SaveNames(ByRef SQLStatement As String)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

    With cmd
        .CommandText = SQLStatement
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Connection = SQLConnection
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    SQLConnection.Close()
    MsgBox("Successfully Added")
    SQLConnection.Dispose()


End Sub

Private Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
    Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO people(name) VALUES (‘" & TextBox1.Text & "')"

    SaveNames(SQLStatement)

End Sub
```

Comment: Is that some sort of smart quote? Are you using MSWord for coding?

Comment: **[How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got one of those microsoft funky quotes, not single quote character

```
VALUES (‘" & 
        ^
```

Replace that with a normal single quote, give it a whirl, and see how big of smoke ball it makes then.